# Way to shorten SQL query with multiple likes in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I got this query about ;"Query the list of CITY names ending with vowels (a, e, i, o, u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates."

The code below works ask expected but i wanna know if i can actually shorten it somehow?

```
select distinct city from station where city LIKE '%A'
or city LIKE '%E'
OR city LIKE '%I'
OR city LIKE '%O'
OR city LIKE '%U'
OR city LIKE '%a'
OR city LIKE '%e'
OR city LIKE '%i'
OR city LIKE '%o'
OR city LIKE '%u';
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT distinct city FROM station WHERE CITY LIKE '%[aeiou]'
```

Comment: This is what i needed. Thank you

Comment: There is a time limit to wait before i can do that  will do so when i can

Answer (score 3):

Get the last character of the string and use `IN()`

```
where RIGHT(city, 1) IN ('E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u')
```

you could also try it case insensitive

```
where RIGHT(city, 1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

If your default collation is case insensitive then this should be sufficient

```
where RIGHT(city, 1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

Comment: This also works and is a great way around that never came to my mind. Thank you

Comment: A complete answer, though the default collations for sqlserver is *mostly* case insensitive and so the collate clause is probably not required. But marks for completeness!